# Drawing a GPUImage over another one with multiply and alpha

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am trying to overlay one image on top of another image with an alpha and multiply blend using GPUImage.  In Core Graphics here is what I was doing.

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage* baseImage = ...;
UIImage* overImage = ...;
CGSize size = baseImage.size;

// Draw the base image
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), baseImage.CGImage);

//Draw the overlay
CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, .5);
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), overImage.CGImage);
```

When I try doing this same thing using GPUImage I can get either the multiply or the alpha to work but I can't get both of them to work.  I feel like there is something with combining GPUImage filters that I don't understand.  Here is one of many different attempts for what I was doing with GPUImage to get this to work.  This version of the code is doing the multiply but not the alpha.

```
GPUImagePicture *pictureOverlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:overImage];
GPUImageOpacityFilter* opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
opacityFilter.opacity = .5;

[pictureOverlay addTarget:opacityFilter];
[pictureOverlay processImage];


pictureOverlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[opacityFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]];

GPUImagePicture *pictureBase = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:baseImage];
GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter *filter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];

[pictureBase addTarget:filter];
[pictureOverlay addTarget:filter];

UIImage* finalImage = [filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the image looks like when I process just using Core Graphics.

[image: CoreGraphics Drawn image]

And here is what I get when I use GPUImage

[image: GPUImage processed]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, I'm currently working with GPUImage and I think the following could work for you :

```
GPUImagePicture *pictureBase = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:baseImage];
GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter *filter = [[GPUImageMultiplyBlendFilter alloc] init];

[pictureBase addTarget:filter];
[pictureBase processImage];

GPUImagePicture *pictureOverlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:overImage];
GPUImageOpacityFilter* opacityFilter = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
opacityFilter.opacity = .5;

[pictureOverlay addTarget:opacityFilter];
[opacityFilter addTarget:filter];
[pictureOverlay processImage];

 UIImage* finalImage = [filter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

It works like a pipeline where results from one filter are the entry for the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I update my original post with the image output I am trying to achieve and the output I get when I use GPUImage using your code above.  The colors do not look right.